# Factory Pattern for Multiple Ctor

Tags: c#, constructor, overloading, factory-pattern

I have a base class with a single constructor.

I also have a factory class which creates instances of the derived classes of base class.

Is it correct to add an overloaded constructor in the base class?

How does the factory class know which constructor to invoke?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: @RohitVats This is a theoretic question. I have learned recently about the factory pattern and would like to understand properly.

Comment: Then try it by yourself and tell us what you have learned by posting your effor in the form of code.

Comment: You could create a method "MySpecialFactoryMethod(list<object> params)". When your list is empty you have to call the ctor without any argument. When your list contains one item you have to call the ctor who takes one argument and so on.